# Is a page with "PROT_NONE bit set" eligible for swapping?

Tags: linux-kernel

From the following link: [Page Table Management - kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand006.html#fig:%20Page%20Table%20Layout), I understood that the bits `PROT_NONE` and `PRESENT` can be used to let the OS know that a page is protected but is resident in memory. I am using these 2 bits to track the pages that are accessed by a process. Here is what I am doing,

1. I clear the `PRESENT` bit and set the `PROT_NONE` bit of pages of a process I want to track so that a page fault occurs when that process tries to access the tracked pages.
2. On page fault, inside __handle_mm_fault before calling handle_pte_fault (x86), I clear `PROT_NONE` and set `PRESENT` if the page is tracked by me. This way, the execution proceeds normally.

But there will be an issue if the page is swapped out meanwhile by the OS. So, I would like to know:

1. If a page with `PROT_NONE` bit set can be swapped out?
2. What happens to the bits `PROT_NONE`, when such a protected page is swapped out? I mean how to distinguish if the page is swapped out or not? Because `PRESENT` bit is cleared already.

Please point out in case any of my understanding is wrong.

Comment: I'm not into the intricacies of the Linux kernel's memory manager, but what stands out as odd to me here is your assertion that "a page fault occurs when the process tries to access the tracked pages". I'm not saying it doesn't, but: *are you sure?* The page fault is normally generated by the CPU when a memory access is attempted to a non-mapped address; it is usually *handled* by the OS by either swapping in the relevant page, or aborting the process (as appropriate).

Comment: As per my understanding by going through the page fault handler code, the process of swapping in a relevant page or some other appropriate action, takes place inside this do_page_fault which is the page fault handler.

Comment: But how would the `PRESENT` bit in some kernel memory management data structure control whether the MMU (or equivalent on other architectures) issues a page fault on access to the relevant address range? I could be completely wrong, but this appears to me like you're getting the chicken and the egg mixed up (no omelette intended).